# composer runtime install command not recognized

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install the fabric composer runtime on my local hyperledger fabric using the composer runtime install command but 'runtime' is not recognized as a command.

```
$ composer runtime install -n manuf-network -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1

Commands:
  archive <subcommand>      Composer archive command
  generator <subcommand>    Composer generator command to convert a Business Network Definition to code
  identity <subcommand>     Composer identity command
  network <subcommand>      Composer network command
  participant <subcommand>  Composer participant command
  transaction <subcommand>  Composer transaction command
  shell                     Interactive shell  [aliases: shell, i]

Options:
  --help         Show help  [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number  [boolean]

Examples:
  composer archive create --inputDir .
  composer identity issue
  composer network deploy
  composer participant add
  composer transaction submit

For more information on Hyperledger Composer: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/

Unknown arguments: n, c, runtime, install
```

I have composer-cli installed as a global.
Here is the version:

```
$ composer --version

composer-cli                   v0.8.1
composer-admin                 v0.8.1
composer-client                v0.8.1
composer-common                v0.8.1
composer-runtime-hlf           v0.8.1
composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.8.1
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed composer-cli (npm uninstall/install -g composer-cli) but still cannot get it to recognize the runtime install command.
I see the latest version of composer is 15 but I can't get my system to recognize anything but 8.1 (see above).

As part of the Installing a Development Environments steps at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html, I installed nvm and am wondering if this has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the newer version of Composer, the "runtime install" command has been changed to "network install", and the --businessNetworkName parameter is no longer required. This command should work:

```
$ composer network install -a your-bna-file.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
```

See more on official documentation here:
[Hyperledger Composer Network Install](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.install.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that composer was installed at multiple locations - (it had been installed as the 8.1 version prior to the recent installation of nvm and as the most recent version subsequent to installation of nvm).  To fix the problem, I found and deleted all instances of composer (from .npm and from .nvm except for in the specific version of node that I am using within nvm).

Comment: the problem for your missing 'runtime install' options is because Hyperledger Composer introduced this from v0.10.0 onwards - see release notes from back then - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.10.0. What OS are you using? Looks like 'Linux' but if you look at the prerequisites https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html you'll see specifically what is minimally required - and NVM in itself won't be the problem, but you did right to clean up your environment. There are big changes, since v0.15.0, you should use that. v0.8.1 is old.